# How to erase Git change on untracked file for now, but show changes in the future

Tags: xcode, git

In Xcode, I mistakenly clicked the `Convert to use Test Plans` button, and Git showed that the `.xcscheme` file had been changed:

```
On branch TestBranch
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    MyProject.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/MyProject-UI-Tests.xcscheme

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I wanted to roll back the change, but the file is untracked, so there's nothing to roll back to.

I tried resetting the HEAD back to the last good commit, but this change stays (which is understandable, since it's not being tracked by Git).

I had a backup copy of the project from the day before, so I was able to restore the `.xcscheme` file manually, which restored Xcode's state back to the way it was prior to clicking the `Convert to use Test Plans` button, so that's good.

However, now that Git is aware that this file has changed, it keeps warning me, even after I restored it to the original state.

The easy fix would be to add the `.xcscheme` name to the `.gitignore` file. However, I don't want Git to ignore the file in the future, in case this happens again for some reason (ie, I like that Git told me which file had been changed, so I knew which one to rollback manually to fix it).

The next best easy fix would be to add the `.xcscheme` file to Git so it *is* being tracked, but my teammates asked me not to include this file because they don't want it being tracked.

So, the question is this: Is it possible to make Git forget the change to `.xcscheme` *up to this point*, but still alert me *if it changes in the future*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, now that Git is aware that this file has changed, it keeps warning me, even after I restored it to the original state.

Git should not "warn you" (about an untracked file) any more after restore than before.
Showing `MyProject-UI-Tests.xcscheme` in the untracked section of `git status` does not mean it has changed, only that is is untracked.
Git cannot forget changes of what it does not track.

Only an external process comparing that file to a pristine copy (a backup you know has the right content) could alert you of any change.

The [OP James Toomey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359088/james-toomey) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74064503/how-to-erase-git-change-on-untracked-file-for-now-but-show-changes-in-the-futur/74065047#comment130778223_74065047):

> I was wrong that this file had been there all along.
>
> There are multiple `.xcscheme` files, but the UI-Tests one only appeared once I clicked that button.
> So, the reason the file appeared in Git's "`untracked files`" section is because this is a new file that had never been there before, so Git is basically saying, "what to do with this new file, do you want to
> a) start tracking it (with `git add`), or
> b) ignore it (by adding it to "`.gitignore`")?

Comment: Hi VonC, thanks for the answer on this. Why would the `MyProject-UI-Tests.xcscheme` file only start appearing once the change had occurred to it? And why is it appearing under the "Untracked files" section? If Git was telling me that the file had changed, and showed it under the "Changes not staged for commit" section, then it would be like any other tracked file that had been changed. This one is behaving differently. What I meant by "Git is warning me" is that it started appearing under the "Untracked files" section when the system changed it, and it's still there despite me reverting it.

Comment: Ahhh, I see my mistake. I was wrong that this file had been there all along. There are multiple .xcscheme files, but the UI-Tests one only appeared once I clicked that button. So, the reason the file appeared in Git's "untracked files" section is because this is a *new* file that had never been there before, so Git is basically saying, "what to do with this new file, do you want to a) start tracking it (with `git add`, or b) ignore it (by adding it to `.gitignore`")?" Is that a pretty good summary of the situation here?

Comment: @JamesToomey Yes, that does sums it up. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. It leveled up my understanding of Git (and Xcode) for sure.